# Django, redirect user for unrecognized url (not just 404 template)

Tags: django

I thought I had this figured out, but just discovered something weird.

In urls I have

```
url('^page_1/$', handle_page_1),
url('^page_2/$', handle_page_2), 
url('^.*/$', handle_page_not_found),
```

`handle_page_not_found()` redirect the user appropriately if the url is not recognized.

That works fine, but I discovered something weird.

If a function returns

```
return HttpResponse("ok")
```

then "ok" is returned and everything seems to work fine. BUT, I just saw that `handle_page_not_found()` is also called (I tested with a print statement). It's still "ok" that is returned, but it's first executing the code in `handle_page_not_found()`.

So, how can I have a function that is called for unrecognized urls, but that is not called by a `HttpResponse` object?

EDIT: Based on answer, saw that my code is actually fine except in special test situation. It's all good so long as the HttpResponse is returned to an ajax call (which is when I normally use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that your browser is doing multiple request to your website.

In particular, it might be trying to request for `/favicon.ico/`.

You can be sure by displaying `request.path` when your handler is called.

Comment: You're right! request.path is /favicon.ico/ This made me look and see that I do not have the issue when I return an HttpResponse to an ajax call. And that's actually the only time I do this except for the test page that I happened to be looking at right now.

Comment: Short version: all is well. My code works except in special test situation.

Comment: for me i believe that it's due to the expression in the last url. for any string it will call handle_page_not_found, change the star to something else.

Comment: @abda2005 Look at the [django URL dispatcher reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). It states: "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL."

Comment: what he get if he move url('^.*/$', handle_page_not_found) to the first position.

Answer (score 3):

avoid the matter with this, it works with me.

urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url('^page_1/$', handle_page_1),
 url('^page_2/$', handle_page_2),
 )
 handler404='views.handle_page_not_found_404'
```

views.py :

```
def handle_page_not_found_404(request):

page_title='Page Not Found'
return render_to_response('404.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

For more details see: [Django documentation: customizing-error-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Redirect404Middleware(object):
     def process_response(self, request, response):
         if response == Http404:
             return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')

         return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for my app with Django v1.11.3 and python v3.6.

Step 1. add view_404 in views.py as following.

```
def view_404(request):
    # do something
    return redirect('/')
```

Step 2. add handler on urls.py.

```
url(r'^.*/$', views.view_404)
```